# Why is NestJS/TypeORM Removing my passed in attribute on save?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am new to Nest JS and trying to setup my first project to get used it. However I have two entities: Organization and User. I have it correctly working for Organization however when I try to create a User I get organizationId IS NULL and cannot save.

This is my entities

```
import { User } from "src/modules/user/entities/user.entity";
import { IOrganization } from "../interfaces/organization.interface";
import { Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryColumn, UpdateDateColumn, OneToMany } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Organization implements IOrganization {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  name: string

  @OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.organization)
  users: User[]

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date
}
```

```
import { Organization } from "src/modules/organization/entities/organization.entity";
import { Column, CreateDateColumn, Entity, PrimaryColumn, UpdateDateColumn, ManyToOne, JoinColumn } from "typeorm";
import { Role } from "../enums/user.enum";

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string

  @ManyToOne(() => Organization, (organization) => organization.users, {
    nullable: false,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: "organizationId" })
  organization: Organization

  @Column({ unique: true, nullable: false })
  email: string
  
  @Column ({
    type: "enum",
    enum: Role,
    default: Role.USER,
    nullable: false,
  })
  role: Role

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  name: string

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date
}
```

Next is my User Module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { OrganizationService } from '../organization/organization.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

This is my User Controller

```
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { UpdateUserDto } from './dto/update-user.dto';
import { Roles } from 'src/decorators/roles.decorator';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

  @Post()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Roles('admin')
  create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    return this.userService.create(createUserDto);
  }

  @Get()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Roles('admin', 'broker', 'assistant')
  findAll() {
    return this.userService.findAll();
  }

  @Get(':id')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Roles('admin', 'broker', 'assistant')
  findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.userService.findOne(+id);
  }

  @Patch(':id')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Roles('admin', 'broker', 'assistant')
  update(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto) {
    return this.userService.update(+id, updateUserDto);
  }

  @Delete(':id')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Roles('admin')
  remove(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.userService.remove(+id);
  }
}
```

And this is my User Service

```
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { UpdateUserDto } from './dto/update-user.dto';
import { IUser } from './interfaces/user.interface';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<IUser> {
    console.log('Created User DTO: ', createUserDto);

    const createdUser = this.userRepository.create(createUserDto);
    console.log('Created User: ', createdUser);
    return await this.userRepository.save(createdUser);
  }

  findAll() {
    return `This action returns all user`;
  }

  findOne(id: number) {
    return `This action returns a #${id} user`;
  }

  update(id: number, updateUserDto: UpdateUserDto) {
    return `This action updates a #${id} user`;
  }

  remove(id: number) {
    return `This action removes a #${id} user`;
  }
}
```

When I hit my create endpoint this is what is console logged:

```
Created User DTO:  {
  id: '6104ac51c617d0d6eb',
  organizationId: '4LYTspbph',
  email: 'test@test.com',
  role: 'admin',
  name: 'test name'
}

Per - First response tried that solution and get this with same error message.

Created User:  User {
  id: '6104ac51c617d0d6eb',
  organizationId: '4LYTspbph',
  email: 'test@test.com',
  role: 'admin',
  name: 'test name'
}
```

Then on the insert in the postgres database is returning this:

`query failed: INSERT INTO "user"("id", "email", "role", "name", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "organizationId") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) RETURNING "role", "createdAt", "updatedAt" -- PARAMETERS: ["6104ac51c617d0d6eb","test@test.com","admin","test name"] error: error: null value in column "organizationId" of relation "user" violates not-null constraint`

I am not sure why its removing the organizationId from the data passed to the function. Can someone help me? This has to be something easy.

I've tried importing the organization modules, and importing a new repository in the constructor with organization but that errors out also. I've tried adding in  Organization in the forFeature import on the users modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @ManyToOne(() => Organization, (organization) => organization.users, {
    nullable: false,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: "organizationId" })
  organization: Organization
```

Here organization is an entity and typeorm does not allow you to insert the ID only rather you need to insert a whole data. Try this -

```
 async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<IUser> {
    console.log('Created User DTO: ', createUserDto);
    const create = this.userRepository.create(createUserDto);
    return await this.userRepository.save(create);
  }
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get the same error, I tried console logged after the new create() but it doesnt get that far to log out that piece. Its still saying organizationId is null

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<IUser> {
    console.log('Created User DTO: ', createUserDto);
    const create = this.userRepository.create(createUserDto);
    const res = await this.userRepository.save(create);
    res.organization = await this.orgrepository.findOne({where:{id: createUserDto.organization}});
await this.userRepository.save(res);
  }
this gonna work confirm